Why does Ubuntu 24.04 no longer auto-mount my phone
I am not sure if this is ONLY an Ubuntu 24.04 issue, but I did upgrade to 24.04 a while back, and today realised I can no longer just plug my phone in and copy files to / from my phone.
lsusb shows the phone connected.
dmesg showed the phone when I plugged it in.
But I can not see it from anywhere else - let alone try and copy files from / to it.
Anybody with a solution ?
Thanks
